# How to change the inner grid style based on the position in Parent Grid

Tags: c#, datagrid, styles

I have a datagrid in which I am using AlternatingRowBackground which displays white and blue colors. I am using RowDetailsTemplate which contains another grid (Inner grid). Inner grid will be displayed when expander(which is present in one of the columns of outer grid) is opened. My problem is, if I click on the expander which is on the row with blue background, I should display my inner grid in blue. If the expander which I am clicking is on the row with white background, then my inner grid should be displayed with white background.

How can i achieve this behaviour?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

try to set the background to colors.transparent...